# Когда уничтожается ValueType и семантика работы GC с ValueType

Tags: .net, память, сборщик-мусора, clr, стек

Ходят мифы и легенды,мол ***ValueType*** удаляется посредством **GC**(то бишь **GC** деаллоцирует как ***ReferenceType***,так и ***ValueType***).
Но на самом то деле это не так. К примеру у нас есть код:

```
class A {}
class B
{
    void TestMethod()
    {
        A a = new A();
        int x = 100;
    }
}
```

в контексте(Scope) метода ***TestMethod()***, создается объект(ReferenceType) типа **А**,а так же переменная **X**(ValueType).

По завершению работы метода, переменная **X** уничтожается,а объект типа **А** теряет ссылку на объект,и становится претендентом для удаления от **GC**.

Иными словами,***ValueTypе*** существует в контексте до тех пор,пока выполняется,и соответственно **Stack**, по типу метода **Pop()** сам удалит эти данные из памяти, и никакого участия в этом не принимает **GC**, поэтому ***ValueType*** и работает быстрее (хотя все зависит от задачи).

И сам вопрос,всегда ли это так работает? (читал разные статьи,иногда пишут,что это происходит только тогда,когда стек забивается, т.е. доходит до заполнения)

Что делает **CLR**,когда стек уже почти переполнен,а все данные в нем к примеру являются ссылками на объекты в куче?
Как и когда удаляются пользовательские структуры? Как именно **CLR** решает удалять ли данные из стека или оставить их еще существовать N-ое кол-во времени!??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Локальные переменные типов ValueType [на которых нет замыканий из анонимных методов и лябмд] лежат прямо в стеке или в регистрах процессора (как захочется оптимизатору).

Вы можете прямо посмотреть, как выполняется ваш код, нажав правой кнопкой по нему в отладке, и выбрав Go To Disassembly, может быть это прояснит картину. Вот как это выглядит в отладочном режиме (что выключает оптимизации). Я добавил комментарии в важных местах:

```
        {
025B2E48  push        ebp     // это так называемый пролог функции
025B2E49  mov         ebp,esp // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue 
025B2E4B  push        edi     // суть его - сохранить текущее положение 
025B2E4C  push        esi     // стека в "базовый указатель" - [e]bp
025B2E4D  push        ebx
```

в стек запихнули значения 3-х регистров, так что его указатель теперь отличается уже на 12 от того, который был в начале функции

```
025B2E4E  sub         esp,3Ch
```

esp - это указатель на начало стека. Уменьшить его на 3Ch - это выделить в стеке 3Сh (60) байт под локальные переменные (или другие накладные расходы)
к этому моменту он уже отличался на 12 от значения, которое лежит в ebp, так что локальные переменные находятся в диапазоне по адресам от [ebp-13] до [ebp-72]. Он же [ebp-0Dh] до [ebp-48h].

Потом делаем кучу проверок и долго и мучительно создаем объект (это все из-за отладочного режима). Я пропущу большую часть кода, она не имеет отношения к вопросу:

```
025B2E51  mov         esi,ecx  
025B2E7C  nop  
            A a = new A();
025B2E7D  mov         ecx,700F98h  
025B2E82  call        024130F4  
025B2E87  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax  
025B2E8A  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-48h]  
025B2E8D  call        025B0D18  
025B2E92  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-48h]
```

и вот наконец ложим указатель на созданный объект в стек (в ebp лежит положение стека на момент начала вызова функции)
    025B2E95  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax

С целым числом попроще - просто запихиваем нужное значение в относительно epb - т.е. относительно начала стека на момент функции.

```
            int x = 100;
025B2E98  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],64h  
        }
025B2E9F  nop
```

А вот теперь фокус. Берем и загружаем в указатель стека значение, которое в нем было сразу после  `025B2E4D  push        ebx`. По сути это `esp = ebp-0Ch`

```
025B2EA0  lea         esp,[ebp-0Ch]  
025B2EA3  pop         ebx  
025B2EA4  pop         esi  
025B2EA5  pop         edi
```

и после следующей строчки получаем значение esp равное тому, которое было в начале функции.

```
025B2EA6  pop         ebp
025B2EA7  ret
```

За счет чего при этом выделалась и освобождалась память в стеке?

Выделалась за счет уменьшения указателя стека на нужное значение. Освобождалась - за счет восстановления старого значения указателя. Расходов на разрушение или "сброрку мусора" локальных переменных при этом не было.

Это стандартный механизм на x86, так что можно считать что так происходит почти всегда. По возврату из функции значение Stack Pointer восстанавливается в то, что было до ее вызова.

Comment: Спасибо за столь раскрытый ответ. Только остался один нюанс,как же все таки обстоят дела с пользовательскими(кастоными) структурами, т.е. когда(и по какому принципу? Такому же как и обычные примитивные данные,типа локальной переменной?) они уничтожаются? Вот эта строчка,  A a = new A(); - подразумевается создание структуры?

Comment: @CSharpUser нет, `new A()` - это ваш класс из примера. С пользовательскими типами дело обстоит точно так же, как с int - просто  под них jit забивает кусок памяти (делает `sub esp, побольше!`, заране решает где в этом куске будет лежать структура, и обращается к ней по смещению от `ebp`. Попробуйте посмотреть Disassembly на своей машине, для разных примеров.

Comment: @CSharpUser на самом деле немного сбивает утверждение "локальные переменные value types храняться в стеке". Потому что на самом деле при этом работы со стеком вида push/pop нет. Компилятор просто отъедает из стека здоровый кусок в самом начале функции, и спокойно раскладывает в этом куске локальные переменные. А в конце фунции весь кусок выбрасывает.